# Excel always convert whole number to decimal

Tags: microsoft-excel

Why do my excel2016 always convert my whole number input to decimal? If I enter 1 in a cell, it automatically becomes 0.01 after I leave that cell. All of the cells are in `General` format.

Comment: Does it happen in only one file / sheet or everywhere? Even after entering the number so you still have "general" format? Is there any macro in the file?

Comment: No. Its everywhere. Even if I create a new fresh file. Still the same.

Comment: @beginner,, check `File` , `Option` then `Advanced` and **un-check**,  `Automatically insert a decimal point` and finally finish with Ok. Better re-start Excel.

Comment: @RajeshS that worked. Thanks.

Comment: Glad to help U @beginner ,,, keep asking ☺